# Deprecation Warning when doing API GET call

Tags: javascript, get, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to call an API using XMLHttpRequest. The code is working fine but I am getting warning which reads :

```
Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.
```

I saw multiple posts on this portal with the same error and some possible solutions but I am unable to figure out whats the solution to fix it for my below code in Javascript.

```
var xhReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhReq.open("GET", api_url, false);
xhReq.send(null);
var jsonObject = JSON.parse(xhReq.responseText);
```

Side note: I am also a beginner to Javascript

Comment: The dupe is a general solution to this problem, but you would probably be better off finding a modern tutorial on using `XMLHttpRequest` (or one for `fetch` which is its more modern successor). https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest

Comment: Also note that `JSON.parse` takes JSON **in** and outputs a JavaScript data structure (object, array, string, maybe something else). `jsonObject` therefore isn't a good name for your variable.